# ¿Cómo contar el valor que más aparece en campo en una base de datos?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Ando atascado en este programa, necesito que me muestre el valor que más veces aparece en una columna determinada, en concreto, que el programa me muestre qué artista aparece más veces en esta lista.

Imagino que es con SELECT COUNT pero no me aclaro.

```python
# Creamos la conexión
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('numerosuno.db')
print("Conexión establecida correctamente")

# Creamos el cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Creamos la tabla
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE canciones (nombre, artista, año, semanas, pais, idioma, continente)')

# Insertamos varios registros a la vez
# usamos el comando .executemany
valores = [('Colgando en tus manos', 'Carlos Baute', 2009, 27, 'Venezuela', 'Español', 'America del Sur'),
           ('Despacito', 'Luis Fonsi', 2017, 26, 'Puerto Rico', 'Español', 'America del Norte'),
           ("You're the One That I Want", 'John Travolta', 1978, 20, 'Estados Unidos', 'Ingles', 'America del Norte'),
           ('Bailando', 'Enrique Iglesias', 2014, 20, 'España', 'Español', 'Europa'),
           ('El Perdon', 'Enrique Iglesias', 2015, 18, 'España', 'Español', 'Europa'),
           ('Sorry', 'Justin Bieber', 2015, 17, 'Canada', 'Ingles', 'America del Norte')
          ]

cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO canciones values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', valores)

# Aplicar los cambios
conn.commit
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. NO sabemos en qué columna buscas ni cuál es la salida de la consulta que deseas. Sin entender bien tu pregunta, podrías probar contando agrupado por la columna de interés y sobre eso buscas el valor más alto.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, espero que ahora esté más claro. Muchas gracias

Comment: Python no es una base de datos. Estás usando SQLite3, que si es una base de datos, como se puede ver en tu código. Lo comento porque el título es incorrecto y te vendría bien añadir las etiquetas etiquetas SQLite y SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Necesitas primero contar las veces que aparece cada valor en dicho campo. En lenguaje SQL, lo que se hace es crear una *agrupación*, que es una operación que *reduce* todas las filas que tengan los mismos valores en las columnas que forman la agrupación a una sola fila.

Junto a agrupar, se utilizan [funciones de agregación](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) que realizan operaciones como sumar `sum()`, promediar `avg()` o **contar** `count()`, entre otras.

La estructura básica de una consulta agrupada es:

```
select campo1, campo2, funcion1(), funcion2()
  from tabla
 group by campo1, campo2
```

Se pueden utilizar tantos campos como se quiera como parte de la agrupación, o incluso, el producto de cálculos realizados con dichos campos.

En tu caso concreto, entonces, lo que necesitamos es una agrupación por artista y la función `count()` para contar cuantas veces aparece en la tabla. Algo como:

```
select artista, count(*) as veces
  from canciones
 group by artista
```

Ahora, necesitamos ordenar este resultado según el número de veces que aparece cada artista, para tener primero el que más aparece, luego el que le sigue, etc.

Esto lo logramos agregando la cláusula [`order by`]. Utilizaremos el índice de la columna y el modificador `desc` para indicar que requerimos un orden descendente, pues lo default es ordenar de menor a mayor:

```
order by 2 desc
```

Finalmente, quieres solamente el artista que aparece más veces, por lo que podemos valernos de la cláusula [`limit`](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_limit_clause) para quedarnos solamente con el primer registro que devuelve la consulta:

```
limit 1
```

Poniendo todo junto, la sentencia que te devuelve el artista que aparece más veces, junto a esa cuenta de las veces que aparece es:

```
select artista, count(*) as veces
  from canciones
 group by artista
order by 2 desc
limit 1
```

Advertencia: Si dos o más artistas *empatan* en la primera posición, esta consulta te devolverá solamente a uno de ellos. Cuál de ellos, es indeterminado. Podríamos agregar un campo más para ordenar, además de por la cuenta, por el nombre mismo del artista, y esto aseguraría que siempre obtendrías al primero o al último en orden alfabético. Si quieres hacer eso, agrega la columna artista a la cláusula `order by`:

```
order by 2 desc, artista
```

Integrar esta consulta a tu programa en python es un ejercicio para el lector.

Comment: Perfecto, por fin he conseguido que me funcione. ¡Muchísimas gracias!